# Небольшие списки постов, элементы которых можно добавлять при помощи поиска с подсказками

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Ищу плагин для Wordpress, который позволит создавать небольшие списки постов (в т.ч. кастомных типов), но не с помощью добавления ID постов через запятую в настройках, а с помощью поиска: вводим в поле первые буквы названия поста - появляются совпадающие варианты из имеющихся постов - выбираем нужный. Следующий элемент по той же схеме. И чтоб их потом сортировать с помощью drag'n'drop можно было.

Comment: Куда добавлять? Что вообще надо решить? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/

Comment: В ACF есть поле